# Does PS Plus help prevent savegame corruption?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I recently encountered a crash in Battlefield 4 and decided to take a break. Out of curiosity, I browsed my PS4's storage to see what's stored inside, and noticed that only the Battlefield 4 savegame was described as *corrupted*. Upon launching the game anew, I had to acknowledge the loss of all of my progress thus far.

In an unrelated case, I decided to subscribe to Playstation Plus. I know that my PS4 will automatically upload savegames to the cloud, as long as I am subsribed to PS Plus, but I was wondering if it also does so for corrupted savegames.

Obviously, if it does I'll have to make sure to disable the auto-upload feature.

So, does my PS Plus subscription help me avoid corrupted savegames, or not?

Comment: You could try to check it yourself if you still have that corrupted save. You have and option to manually upload save game data to the "PS+ cloud". You could try to upload this corrupted save, and if you will be unable to do so, I guess automatic updated wouldn't be able either.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Unfortunately, Battlefield 4 automatically replaced my corrupted save with a fresh one, so unless the crash happens again, I won't be able to test this out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's likely to help as long as the savedata is uploaded to PS Plus before the corruption happens. It's a good idea to disable the auto-upload feature if you're worried about corrupted data being saved to the cloud.

I haven't experienced any savedata corruption, but I assume that corrupted savedata would be uploaded to the cloud too as the cloud wouldn't actually know if the data is corrupted. Hopefully, the PS4 safeguards against this by not uploading corrupted data to start with.

Comment: Assuming the console is able to determine that data has been corrupted, I wouldn't expect it to upload a corrupted save. Although I'm not sure how that's determined and how reliable it is.

Comment: I can confirm that corrupted saves do get pushed to the cloud. Happened to me with Battlefield 4.  The best option I found was to manually push my save to a flash drive after I was done playing single player.  The cloud should work too, I didn't realize you could disable auto-upload.